# Is it possible in angular.js to call function in every controller?

Tags: angularjs

Hello im new to angular and I have a question that gave me some trouble, with researching and trying to make it work. Same task in knockout.js gave me no problems so I was wondering if it's possible in angular too.

So I have:

```
<td ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-model="Element">`
<element-template style="position: static" ng-model="Element" el="element">`
</element-template>
```

and every repetition is giving me one controller to the html template looking something like this

```
<div ng-model="el" class="element">
</div>
```

And the whole thing gets the data from 
    `pageController.controller[...]`
that controlls the array in which there is a data for elements.
Every element has its own controller which look something like this:

```
pageController.directive('Element') {
  var controller = ['$scope', [...] , function ($scope, [...])
  {
    //code
    $scope.save() = function(){
        console.log("save successful");
    }
  }
}
```

And now the question:
Is there a way for the pageController to make every element's controller to execute save() of the element?

In knockout I would just subscribe a function to the change of some observable in the element controller and in there just call the function but I couldn't find a way to do same thing in angular. Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is repeated or too trivial.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  This *feels like* an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  Instead of asking about what it is you are trying to solve, you are asking about how to make angular do something the same way another framework did it.  It's more likely that there is some direct way that angular handles the problem you are faced with, but it's hard to understand what that is from here.  I say that because, with angular two way binding, you don't actually have to "save" every input, they are already automatically updating.

Comment: Yep, use  a combination of `$scope.$on`, `$scope.$emit` and `$scope.$broadcast`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try to make a better question next time.

Comment: And also reading documentation about the combination of things you mentioned I think that is what I need thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure I am following what you need, maybe a plunkr with a sample of your code would help.
But if you are repeating an ng-model directive you can use the `$index` property to distinguish between your elements.

So instead of just el, do this to bind to an array `$scope.el = [];` in your page controller:

```
<td ng-repeat="element in elements">
  <input type="text" ng-model="el[$index]" />
</td>
```

Also using ng-model in a div doesn't do anything, it only makes sense inside a input to double bind the value.
I think you need to do some tutorials on the subject, it seems like you are unaware of how things are scoped and how ng-repeat works.

if are trying to access the objects within the elements array,  for example you have an array of objects called elements:

```
$scope.elements = [
   { title: "one"},
   { title: "two"},
   { title: "three"},
];
```

You would then do this in your ng-repeat:

```
<td ng-repeat="element in elements">
  <input type="text" ng-model="element.title" />
</td>
```

Comment: I simplified the code to make it more readable, let me explain.
   <td ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-model="Element">
    <element-template style="position: static" ng-model="Element"
     el="element"></element-template>
    </td>

Comment: It seems like you are also unsure of how directives work, so if you want to repeat a directive, you can do the same as my example and replace the input tag with your directive. Your sample code for your element-template tag is meaningless without posting the directive's JS code

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about. The directive for every generated element is 'Element' directive mentioned in the orginal post, but the controller for the whole page (where ng-repeat takes place and where I want to make a button that invokes function of every element) is pageController

Comment: I also edited the orginal post for you to include more code.

Comment: But it didn't, phuzi's answer is actually the correct one.